# My Dynamic Web Project welcome-file doesn't get affected by changes

Tags: java, html, eclipse, jsp

This is a pretty strage and hassle problem i have here.

I created a Dynamic Web Project in Eclipse and created an HTML file named "inicio.html".
I put this into my web.xml `<welcome-file>` and all seemed to work okay.
I could Run on server without any problem.

Until i dragged a folder into my webapp.
[folder in my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GIeDZ.png)

Now when i run on server my file doesnt change at all, and even when i change the welcome-file from web.xml it doesn't change.

It looks like there's another file somewhere like a copy from the original "inicio.html" that's executing on my server.

[this is an example of what's happening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fktUd.png)

I tried to change my TomCat's web.xml file and it doesn't works.

Answer (score 0):

It's unlikely that the new IMG folder is relevant. Deployment Descriptors aren't really hot swappable.

Make sure automatic building is enabled on the Project menu, and then try right-clicking on the server in the Servers View and choosing "Clean Tomcat Work Directory". Otherwise, you'll need to restart the server for changes to take effect.